# How To Approve Commits On Github

Tags: git, github

I have a project on Github and I want to create two distinct teams of contributors.

The first team will be a push/pull self-organising team of people who can make changes at will.

The second team will be people who are new to the project and need more guidance.

I would like to be able to "approve" the changes made by the second team - i.e. peer review them and help them to better understand our standards and the direction of the project.

How do I set the permissions so they can make changes, but those changes need to be approved?

Comment: Ehh. Are you going to tell facebook questions "Shouldn't you ask facebook", Java questions "Shouldn't you ask at the official Oracle forum?", etc...

Comment: Thanks gladoscc. @Abizern We ask questions on Stack because we like the fact that we get not just answers, but other people helping us to choose the correct answer by voting them up. That's why this site is so awesome!

Comment: what's the difference between approving a commit and approving a pull-request in terms of the UI etc?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add the “trusted” developers as collaborators (Repository Administration → Collaborators); that gives them full read/write access. The rest of the developers can fork the repository and issue a pull request when they want to merge something back. You’ll do a code review in the pull request and if it’s fine, merge it.

Comment: Do I need to add people to a team for them to do a pull request, or can anyone on github do that?

Comment: If it is a public team, anyone can do that.

Comment: I see - thanks guys, I thought I had to grant permissions to someone before they could do that. Thanks.

Comment: What if the repo and team is not public?

Answer (score 4):

with the latest feature launched by github, now it can be done out of the box for any member in team (better to have for all rather than excluding some).

**Steps:**

1. [Configure](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-protected-branches/) Protected Branches
2. [Disable Merge Button](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-reviews/#required-reviews) until commit changes are approved by a peer

More Details [Here ...](https://help.github.com/articles/about-required-reviews-for-pull-requests/)
[image]
Edited the answer as the 1 big issue with forked repo is fixed now

Comment: Edited the answer as now the issue with forked branches is resolved and its usable feature for any branch which is protected within the project

Answer (score 1):

The team which needs to be approved can pack their changes in patches and send them to a patch-queue (extra repo or special mail). The main developer team can then approve the code and apply the patch if it qualifies for it.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the commits name and on your top right you will see a dropdown. You can either approve or reject.

Hope this helps?